# Javascript: How to truly reload a site with an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, url, anchor, reload

Take this code snippet for example:

```
window.location.href = 'mysite.htm#images';
```

Already being on the site `mysite.htm` and triggering the reload thru `location.href` won't reload the page but jump to the anchor named within the URL.

I need a mechanism to truly reload the page. Any ideas?

PS: I tried location's other methods but none of them does the trick :(

**EDIT**
Don't hang on the filetype `htm`. I'd need it for dynamic sites as well.

Comment: `onclick="alert('Please press F5')"`

Comment: So you want to reload the page, AND then jump to the name-anchor?

Comment: @Pbirkoff Yep, exactely.
@nickf Hehe, you made my day :D

Comment: @nickf best location.reload alternative ever :D

Answer (score 57, accepted):

After you set the specified URL into location, issue `window.location.reload(true)`. This will force browser to reload the page.

Comment: I'm finding this causes the page to reload the page's original URL, not the one that was just set.  (I agree that it should work as you describe, though.)

Comment: That will cause browser to do full reload of *everything* with HTTP header `Pragma: no-cache` which causes much more to be downloaded but just the host document (usually HTML page) as expected.

Comment: Also note that according to the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload the `reload()` does not take any arguments.

Comment: Also note that according to spec you *may* get an old copy from the cache or a new copy from the server depending on the user agent: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-reload - the spec only says that "User agents **may** allow the user to explicitly override any caches when reloading."

Comment: I found this would repeat a `POST` if that was the previous request, whereas I wanted a `GET`.  I therefore used `<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174282/link-to-reload-current-page#15424546

Answer (score 10):

use the query part of the URL to add a random string:

```
// Use a timestamp to make sure the page is always reloaded
window.location.href = 'mysite.htm?r='+(+new Date())+'#images';
```

Answer (score 6):

While I feel alemjerus's answer is on the good direction, it *doesn't work when the new URL points to different page*, at least on my Chrome v40.

Example, when the new URL just add an anchor, it works fine:

```
var redirectToURL = '/questions/2319004/javascript-how-to-truly-reload-a-site-with-an-anchor-tag#answer-28621360';
window.location.href = redirectToURL;
window.location.reload(true);
```

But when it points to a different page, user will still stay on the current page after reload. (Run the following codes in a batch, no delay between `location.href=` and `location.reload`):

```
var redirectToURL = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
window.location.href = redirectToURL;
window.location.reload(true);
```

In this case, remove the `location.reload` works. So my workaround is to check whether new URL is on the same page:

```
var urlParser = document.createElement('a');
urlParser.href = redirectToURL;
if (urlParser.origin + urlParser.pathname === location.origin + location.pathname) {
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Tested on Chrome and Safari, haven't tried IE. Kindly let me know if it doesn't work on any major browser.

Answer (score 3):

You could be a cheater and append a randomized query string, redirecting to "mysite.htm?random=289954034#images".

But if this is a static page, as `.htm` implies, what do you need reloading for? If it's so that your onload Javascript can occur a second time, maybe you just need to change your application's flow.

Comment: Don't let the extension fool you. You can just rewrite urls to make them look like they are html files.

Comment: It's true, but only rarely have I seen a rewriter choose `.htm` over `.html`. That's why I chose the word "implies" :)

Comment: It's not about static vs. dynamic pages when AJAX comes into play. Think about it.

Comment: ...eh? Then you shouldn't need to refresh the page if you're using AJAX... I should probably just not try to analyze someone else's system without knowing any details at all xD

Answer (score 3):

I found that the answer by @alemjerus would retrigger a `POST` if that was the last request:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

What I wanted was to refresh the page from scratch using a `GET`, so I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174282/link-to-reload-current-page#15424546):

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">Refresh page</a>
```

Comment: This is correct answers which refreshes current page wout any extra line of code. Working by just adding script directly inside the attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`window.location.href = 'mysite.htm?';`

**EDIT:** This will only work the first time; after that, the caching takes effect again.

Answer (score -2):

Works with most of the Mozilla browsers

```
<a title="Reset this Document" href="javascript:void()" onclick="window.location.href='#'"><font color="red">Reset</font></a>
```

Code Line:

```
window.location.href='#'
or window.location.href=''
```

The last code will not work properly with IE