# location href with anchor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm on a page, let's say page.php, and I want to reload it.
Here is my first code:

```
$(location).attr("href", "/page.php");
```

it perfectly works : the page reloads well.

Now, I'd like to go to a specific place into my page, using anchors:

```
$(location).attr("href", "/page.php#anchor");
```

When I do this, browser goes directly to the anchor indeed, without reloading the page, wich isn't what I want.

How could I reload the page **THEN** go to my anchor?

Comment: `location.href` would do the same thing.

Comment: jQuery is primarily for manipulating the DOM, not arbitrary objects. `location` is such an object for which it does not make sense to pass it to jQuery.

Comment: `location` is not an element.  Don't treat it as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to truly reload a site with an anchor tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319004/javascript-how-to-truly-reload-a-site-with-an-anchor-tag) At least, the advice given there should suffice in your case. )

Comment: Why are you doing `$(location).attr("href")`?  Where did you learn that?

Comment: I'm surprised that it's working; jQuery constructor function is really an omnivore. :)

Comment: @raina77ow you were right :) Your post helped me.

Comment: Wow, this seems like a simple problem to solve at first!  I reckon __[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2319021/706561)__ is your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

You can try window.location.reload()

Comment: Why? Can you explain please?